# ClosedXML Gives 'File Corrupt' Error, But File is Not Corrupt (VB.net)

Tags: excel, vb.net, closedxml, corrupt

I am using the ClosedXML package (version 0.95.4) to open an Excel file (.xlsx), which was previously saved in a folder to which the application has access.  This is proven by the fact that the application can save to this folder.

However, when I attempt to open the file using ClosedXML, I receive an error that the file is corrupt.

> System.IO.FileFormatException: 'File contains corrupted data.'

When I open the file directly using Excel, the file opens normally, with no errors.  I should also add that this code was working perfectly before, and suddenly stopped working.

This is the code where the file is saved.

```
' Save the file to standard temp folder
Dim dirDownloads As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath
Randomize()
Dim strFileCode As String = (CInt(Int(Rnd() * 99999999)) + 10000000).ToString & "_" & fn
Dim fp As String = dirDownloads & "\" & strFileCode
fp = Replace(fp, "\\", "\")

fup_ESPM.SaveAs(fp)
```

For clarity, fup_ESPM is a [FileUpload control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.8).

And this is the code where ClosedXML attempts to open the file.

```
Sub SQL_Upload_ESPM_Template_Data(FilePath As String)
    ' Open target file
    Dim cxlDoc As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(FilePath) ' This is the line where the error is occuring
```

Comment: As we don't know what fup_ESPM is and what it does, there's only some thoughts for shareing. Please consider improving your question.

Comment: 1.) fup_ESPM might not be done writing when ClosedXML loads the file
2.) fup_ESPM might propably write something that is not implemented correctly or at all in ClosedXML
3.) you may have encountered a bug that is already [reported to ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues), please take a look there.

Comment: Thanks, @DerSchnitz.  I have edited the question to denote that fup_ESPM is a FileUpload control.  I'll also examine the link relating to the bug you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assume fup_ESPM then should not be the problem. Did you doublecheck if ClosedXML can load that file locally without the upload like with a little console app? Does the file contain images, diagrams or complex pivots?

Comment: @DerSchnitz Thanks for the advice.  I've determined that the differentiator is the file itself, and not anything in my code.  I created a simple VB.net application to open the file directly, and got the same error.  However, when I opened another Excel file from the same folder, there was no issue.  I'm not sure what, since the file does not contain any of the elements you specified.

Unfortunately, the Excel file is generated by a third-party website that I have no control over.  At least now I know the code isn't deficient.

Comment: Uhm, ok, then we at least know it's specific to certain files. The elements I mentioned where causes for errors I encountered in the past - there might of course exist more I did not stumble over, yet. It also could just be a badly formated source file. As you might know, xlsx is just a specificly formated xml structure in a zip archive - debugging that is vastely inconvinient, tho. You might want to try another Excel reader component in your code, ex. [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader) is open source as well. Sorry for not having exacly a solution, good luck!